# How to increase the width of a scroll bar for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there way to increase the width of the scroll bars for a DataGridView ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way of doing it is by implementing your own control and replacing the one on the `DataGridView`. I found this on CodeProject(its VB but still a good example):

[Core Custom Scrollbar Class By VectorX](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/corescrollbar.aspx)

There is also something on the MSDN forums

[custom scrollbar for datagridview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/08c5425e-881d-4681-bf8b-60a40f4ebc4a/)

Answer (score 2):

Both the scrollbars are within the DataGridView's Control collection.  You can simply get them from there and try alter it.

Comment: Thanks for the response
Picked up HScrollBar from the DataGridView's Control Collection and tried changing it. But no luck..

Comment: Did you call Refresh after changing?

Comment: The problem is that they are read-only and protected so no modifications there.