# Change size of Scrollbar on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, scrollbar

I need to change the size of the (incorporated) vertical scrollbar on a DataGridView.
I'm working on a Windows-Form and can't seem to find a solution.
I tried to change the size with properties, but apparently this is not possible since the only available modifications to turn the scrollbar on or off.

I don't have any experience in editing components and don't know where/how to start.

I'd be grateful for any help
Cheers, Dan.

Comment: Changing the default vertical scroll bar in a `datagridview` will be challenging but doable… Changing check boxes on another… is another question. Glad to help but your question is vague and shows not attempt. You may want to peruse… [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) …  AND [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay thank you.
But I don't understand how I should give you an examples? I have a DataGridView and want to change the size of the scrollbar...

Comment: This is resolved in a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462772/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-scrollbars-on-a-datagridview-control

Comment: Probably not the exact thing you are looking for, but you can get started here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906145/how-to-increase-the-width-of-a-scroll-bar-for-datagridview

What you are asking is not possible using the native libraries. You will have to write your own code to generate a scrollbar like here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7791/Core-Custom-Scrollbar-Class

Comment: Not knowing what your requirements are… WHY do you need to change this? Changing the size of the vertical scroll bar seems like an unnecessary cosmetic change. Your choices may be limited to implementing your own inherited control for this?

Comment: try to look in to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224/change-the-width-of-a-scrollbar just inform us if it is your goal